# SharePoint Online Refinable Properties and Custom Content Types

Tags: content-type, sharepoint-online

We're using SharePoint Online (Office365) post-upgrade, plan E3.

I have created a custom content type based on the standard Task. When I assign a crawled property to one of the RefinableString refinable mapped properties, it gets picked up for standard tasks, but not for the custom content type. I have verified this using the Search Refinement web part, and using a REST query (simple browser URL, no coding for me).

How can I get the Refinable properties to get picked up by the other content type? For reference, I have mapped the following crawled properties to refinable managed properties in an attempt to troubleshoot:

- ows_Assignedto
- ows_q_user_AssignedTo
- ows_SiteName

These are all direct copies of managed properties that DO work for the custom content type, but by default are not refinable.

Because I'm using Office365, I can't create new managed properties (only use the pre-defined RefinableStringnn properties and map them), nor can I initiate a full crawl. Some things are simply left in the hands of MS.